# Switching data and apps between 2 Nexus phones

Tags: backup, restore, nexus

Is there any fast or easy way to switch apps and data between 2 Nexus phones?

First is Nexus 5 running Android 6.0.1 MOB30Y, second one is Nexus 4 running Android 5.1.1 LMY48T

Comment: What do you mean by "switching"? Taking literally, two devices with completely different configuration (including apps installed) changing their roles? Or do you rather want to keep things in sync?

Comment: Changing roles is the right idea

Comment: In that case, no easy fast way I'm afraid. All I'm aware of would go along the lines of backing up the entire two devices, wiping them, and restoring cross-wise. Untried possible alternative: using profiles on both devices and syncing those cross-wise.